# How to lazy load jspm module with angular 2?

Tags: angular, systemjs, jspm

I am trying to load a bundle dynamically.
I have my main bundle, and for the lazy loaded bundle I do:

```
jspm bundle-sfx src/comps/app1/App1.js out.js --skip-source-maps
```

and in the angular2 code I run

```
if (condition){
   return System.import('/dist/public/out.js').then(c => c[name]);
}
```

the problem is that I am getting an error of:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: AMD module http://localhost:8003/dist/public/out.js did not define
```

Is there something special I need to do to be able to load App1 dynamically (lazy load)?

(if I don't bundle lazy loading is working great by the way)...

my config.js is:

```
...
packages: {
    "src": {
        "main": "App",
        "defaultExtension": "ts",
        "meta": {
            "*.js": {
                "loader": "ts"
            },
            "*.ts": {
                "loader": "ts"
            },
            "*.css": {
                "loader": "css"
            }
        }
   ...
```

so as you can see I didn't put any special package entry for App1 (don't think I need to?!?!?!)

tx and regards

Sean.